fill in a cycle that uses a combination of "plot coordinates" and point "to" point
I'd like my fill to fill in the entire lune shape.  Instead, the my code is only filling the distance between straight lines between coordinates and their respective curves.  Here's the code with which I'm working:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (A2) at (6,0);
            \coordinate (top s2) at (3,1);
            \coordinate (bottom s1) at (3,-1);
            \coordinate (top left s3) at (1.6,0.8);
            \coordinate (top right s3) at (4.4,0.8);
            \coordinate (bottom left s2) at (1.4,-0.75);
            \coordinate (bottom right s2) at (4.6,-0.75);

            \draw[fill=gray!25] 
                (A1) to[out=37, in=200] (top left s3) 
                plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates 
                    {(top left s3) (top s2) (top right s3)}
                (top right s3) to[out=-20, in=140] (A2)
                (A2) to[out=220, in=20] (bottom right s2) 
                plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates 
                    {(bottom right s2) (bottom s1) (bottom left s2)}
                (bottom left s2) to[out=160,in=-37] (A1);

            \filldraw (A1) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (A2) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (top s2) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (bottom s1) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (top left s3) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (top right s3) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (bottom left s2) circle (0.05cm);
            \filldraw (bottom right s2) circle (0.05cm);

            \node[left] at (A1) {$\hat s_1$};
            \node[right] at (A2) {$\hat s_1$};
            \node[above] at (top s2) {$\hat s_2$};
            \node[below] at (bottom s1) {$\hat s_1$};
            \node[above] at (top left s3) {$\hat s_3$};
            \node[above] at (top right s3) {$\hat s_3$};
            \node[below] at (bottom left s2) {$\hat s_2$};
            \node[below] at (bottom right s2) {$\hat s_2$};

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

And here's the corresponding picture


Replacing plot by -- plot and removing repeating coordinates after a plot operation (i.e remove the second (Foo) in plot[…] coordinates {… (Foo)} (Foo)) will fll the whole shape. Instead of (A1); write cycle;, it will make for a cleaner joint at that point (this is hidden by the circles here though).

Off topic: Isn't this simply a lens and not a lune? Either way, why don't you draw this with an arc?

@Qrrbrbirlbel  Yes!  Technically it is a lens.  I'm ultimately working within a sphere (hence lune) but have been having problems  drawing the respective great circles (see tex.stackexchange question "final great circle to draw triange group (2,3,4)").  And thank you for the suggestion to draw it with an arc!

@Qrrbrbirlbel  Perfect!!  This worked!!  Thank you very much!
